# return a value via function math result that is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript

i was trying to get a result of the browsers  window width and trying to put the result of math and condition in a variable , this is the code

```
var MyWidth = 1900;
var MyHeight = 900;
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();

var AutoW = function () {
    if ( (MyWidth / width).toFixed(2) > 0.95 )
          return 1;
    if ( (MyWidth / width).toFixed(2) < 1.05 )
          return 1;
    else return (MyWidth / width).toFixed(2);
     };


alert(AutoW);
```

the problem is i don't know the right syntax or structure of the function assigned to the variable

what is the right way to code this ?

Comment: AutoW is just the function defined at runtime , try to call alert(AutoW()), you will get value. now if you want to get value of this function into AutoW , then declare another function and call it with assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert(AutoW());`

`AutoW()` returns the value of function assigned to the variable.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/V2esf/

Comment: oh i did not pay attention to that or better said , did not know that rule..thought something is wrong with the code itself

Answer (score 1):

```
var AutoW = function () {
    // don't calculate ratio 3 times! Calculate it once
    var ratio = (MyWidth / width).toFixed(2);
    if (ratio > 0.95)
          return 1;
    if (ratio < 1.05)
          return 1;
    else return ratio;
};


// alert(AutoW); - this was a problem, AutoW is a function, not a variable
// so, you should call it
alert(AutoW());
```

Comment: sure i thought of issue  (:,  but thanks for a full answer (i was still in stage one of thinking it when had that 'problem')

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var MyWidth = 1900;
    var MyHeight = 900;
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();

    var AutoW = function () {
        if ((MyWidth / width).toFixed(2) > 0.95)
            return 1;
        if ((MyWidth / width).toFixed(2) < 1.05)
            return 1;
        else return (MyWidth / width).toFixed(2);
    };

    var val = AutoW();
    alert(val)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this way:

```
(function(){

var MyWidth = 1900,
MyHeight = 900,
height = $(window).height(),
width = $(window).width(),
result;

var AutoW = function () {
    var rel = (MyWidth / width).toFixed(2);
    return ( ( rel > 0.95 ) && ( rel < 1.05 )) ? 1 : rel;
};

result = AutoW();

alert(result);

})();
```

But remember the function you wrote always returns 1, that is why I changed it for (&&) condition to make it a filter.

if you make alert of function, you will return the entire function. you have to asign the cast of a function "()" to a variable so the return will be asigned to it.

```
var result = f_name();
```

And remember, try not to use global variables, wrap everything in a function.

You should put  {} after if, and cache values that you are using many times like when I cached "(MyWidth / width).toFixed(2)" into rel.

The sintax I used instead of if >>  (condition) ? (return if match) : (return else);

Comment: nice one , could you remind me the name of " condition  ? return : return else "?

Comment: Ternary operators and short conditionals :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx